# Why can't this kill White Walkers in Season 8 Episode 3?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

After the latest episode, I have some doubt about what can kill a White Walker and why.

We know, as a fact, that both Valyrian Steel and dragonglass can kill White Walkers, and they have in common being forged by dragon fire, which I initially thought was the reason they had this power.

In the latest episode, though,

> we see the Night King stand untouched in one of the arguably strongest breaths of dragon fire, made with the sole purpose of killing him

That scene gives me lots of doubt.

> if dragon fire cannot kill White Walkers, why should things forged with it do it? We can argue Valyrian steel has been enchanted in the forging process, but weapons made from dragonglass have clearly not been, yet they have been shown to kill White Walkers.
> Why can't the dragon fire kill the White Walkers?

Comment: Neither Valyrian Steel nor Obsidian are forged by Dragonfire.

Comment: I've reworded your question to the specific event we see in the show because the broader "what can kill and why" would be a duplicate.

Comment: @Aegon in-universe lore says so, according to https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Valyrian_steel

Comment: @bracco23 Can't speak for fan-maintained GoT wiki. It is unreliable and public. Refer to AWOIAF instead which is authentic. Or since AWOIAF is exclusively about Show canon, you can look up the references from the show wiki, verify if there's any basis to those claims yourself.

Comment: @Aegon AWOIAF is less explicit, but it does mention Valyrian steel being forged with dragon with a reference to a book chapter https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Valyrian_steel

Comment: @bracco23 Could you quote the statement please? I can't find it. If it is there, I'll be happy to check it up for you.

Comment: Valyrian steel requires specific spells, so even if dragonfire is used, it is not the only/main source of magic.

Comment: @Aegon "Valyrian steel, possibly forged with dragons", with a reference to chapter 72, but on the synopsis of chapter 72 no reference to such statement is made.

Comment: @bracco23 Ah Dany says `"Ser Jorah Mormont," she said, "first and greatest of my knights, I have no bride gift to give you, but I swear to you, one day you shall have from my hands a longsword like none the world has ever seen, dragon-forged and made of Valyrian steel. And I would ask for your oath as well."` Tbf it doesn't seem to imply that Valyrian steel has to be dragonforged. Just that Dany promises him one that will be Dragonforged.

Comment: "She nodded, as calmly as if she had not heard his answer, and turned to the last of her champions. "Ser Jorah Mormont," she said, "first and greatest of my knights, I have no bride gift to give you, but I swear to you, one day you shall have from my hands a longsword like none the world has ever seen, dragon-forged and made of Valyrian steel. And I would ask for your oath as well."" This can be both, exclusive things to the sword. Iron throne was dragon-forged, but nothing magic on it

Comment: @Kepotx It is claimed that the Iron Throne has the magical ability to spurn a ruler who is unworthy of it by cutting him/her (Which is seen as a huge sign of illegitimacy). Maegor was spurned by the throne (And supposedly killed), Rhaenyra was spurned by the throne, Aerys II got cut so often that he was called King Scabs, Joffrey was spurned by the throne. But OTOH we also have Viserys I who cut his hand on the throne (Although we can claim that he was unworthy because he sowed seeds of the Dance) and Aegon IV, the most unworthy King who never got cut.

Comment: @Aegon I always assumed that Aegon made a seat full of pointy end in purpose, so it would be litteraly uncomfortable to sit in the throne, leading to lot of cuts, and that the ordeal-like thing was just created to defame any ruler